# How do I send data from BeautifulSoup to a database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I want to try to send my data obtained with BeautifulSoup from the website to a database table, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

I have no idea how to solve it, I would like the downloaded data to be in the table called "headers".

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3


con=sqlite3.connect('scrap.db')
cur=con.cursor()
      
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS headers (
            header text
            ) ''')



req=requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/?ref=upstract.com&curator=upstract.com&utm_source=upstract.com')
req.status_code



soup=BeautifulSoup(req.content,'html.parser')
contentRedid=soup.find_all("h3",{"class":"_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m"})
for content in contentRedid:
      
      headers=content.getText().strip()
      query='INSERT INTO headers VALUES (%s)' #ERROR sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
   
      cur.execute(query,headers) 
      
      con.commit()
    
      con.close()
      
      
      
      
      
      
# print(contentRedid)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the problem is here:

```
query='INSERT INTO headers VALUES (%s)' #ERROR sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

You need to use the correct syntax to bind variables to your query.

- Pass a ? to indicate where the parameter should be inserted in your query.
- Pass your query and a tuple of variables to `cursor.execute`.

  ```
  query='INSERT INTO headers VALUES (?)' 
  parameters=(headers,)
  cur.execute(query, parameters )
  ```